# max_execution_time is 240 second - exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds

Tags: php, laravel, centos

I'm using this package to run my bash:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
```

I got this error when I want to run my bash inside laravel:

> The process ***/my.sh exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.

```
$process = new Process('sh ***/my.sh');
       $process->run();

       // executes after the command finishes
       if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
          throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
       }
```

my `max_execution_time` inside `phpinfo` function is 240. I restarted my server.
my `safe_mode` is off. I used this function :

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

above my code, but after 60 seconds I got the same error message.
my `.htdaccess` is 240 seconds.

any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Process` class has a timeout of its own, according to [Process docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#process-timeout):

> By default processes have a timeout of 60 seconds, but you can change it passing a different timeout (in seconds) to the `setTimeout()` method:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process('sh ***/my.sh');
$process->setTimeout(240);
$process->run();
```

You should check the `idleTimetout` as well, if the process may take a long time without outputing any data:

```
$process->setIdleTimeout(240);
```

The docs doesn't say anything about using `0` as no limit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable the `setTimeout` or `setIdleTimeout` completely, simply set them as `null`:

```
$process->setTimeout(null);
$process->setIdleTimeout(null);
```